# How to redo formatted text after being deleted?

Tags: python, tkinter, tags

I have the following situation regarding Python and tkinter:

Let's say that we have a button that, when you click on it, inserts a sentence with blue characters in the Text widget. The color is due to a `.add_tag()` and `.tag_config()` for making the tagged characters to be blue.

```
some_text.tag_config('s', foreground = 'royal blue')
```

If you hit `Undo` or `Ctrl-Z`, or you delete the piece of text, and then call `Redo`: the text shows up again but the characters are not blue anymore. This makes me think that the `Undo`- `Delete` actions strips the formatted text from the tags.

So, how can I restore/`Redo` formatted text (tagged text) that has been deleted either by a `tkinter.Text.delete()` command, `Backspace`, or by `Undo`?

Thank you.

Comment: Create local step(data) container and bind function `ctrl+z/y` on main-loop. No have any magical way for related question. Load all text and accessible variables to container and shift-left /shift-right container data, off course you need trace container data.

Comment: Yeah, I thought about something similar. To have a class that acts like a stack, storing text edition -including the tags-, and do the proper changes when calling undo/redo. I read that tkinter has a built in stack for that purpose, but I do not know how to access it in order to check what stores and how does it do it. I do not want to reinvent the wheel if there is one already.